# class import : ImproperlyConfigured: The SECRET_KEY setting must not be empty

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I have this error whenever I try to import model class from another app. in a helper file `helper.py`.

Project structure:

```
project_dir
    - main_project_dir
    - helpers
         - helper.py
    - malakar_app
         - models.py <- contains RunDate model class
```

Now in `helper.py`:

```
from django.conf import settings
from project.models import RunDate

def get_run_date_id_from_rundate_field(ac_id, run_date):
    try:
        run_date = RunDate.object.get(file_run_date=run_date, client_id=ac_id)
        return run_date.id
    except RunDate.DoesNotExist:
        return None
```

I read something similar about `circular dependency` but have no idea how to proceed.

How can I import the model class in the helper file?

Comment: The error message complains about an empty `SECRET_KEY`. That is a value in `settings.py`. Is it set there?

Comment: @C14L yes.. btw I solved this by creating another `model_helper.py` file in the same dir. instead of `helper.py`.